# SSL connection error when browsing Facebook and Twitter

Tags: ssl

I get this error not always but most of the times I try to go to Facebook or Twitter:

> SSL connection error
>
> Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have. Error code: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Sometimes I log in to my computer, I am able to access Facebook but most of the times I get this error. I have tried all the tips and tricks I have found but unable to find anything that could help me solve this problem. This was working fine some weeks ago but not sure what has changed and I cannot go back in time with Windows I don't have this restore point I would need.

Facts: Windows 7 64 bits - Chrome or just any browser. Logged in to Linkedin works fine but not Twitter or Facebook. Gmail works fine.

Any idea what could cause this error?

Comment: Who is the Issuer of the certificate you see when you go to LinkedIn? Do you use a proxy server? Are you at home or work or college?

Comment: I am at home.
No I dont use proxy server. 
How can I see what certificat I use when logged in to Linkedin?

Comment: Are you sure your ISP isn't messing with anything? Does `ping facebook.com` work?

Comment: Also, do you have any mobile devices you can test your connection with? Try using something other than your computer, connect to your home connection, and try going to facebook. If it works, you know your computer is messing it up, if it doesn't, then your ISP is.

Comment: ping works. My iphone with wireless works.

Comment: That's strange. Your OS is probably acting up. I hate to say this, but if you don't have any restore points you may have to actually reinstall Windows.

Comment: I can visit m.facebook.com in browser but not https://www.Facebook.com   any idea what is the difference?